# Connected Storage broken?

Tags: xbox-live

Today **GameSaveProvider::GetForUserAsync()** started returning **GameSaveErrorStatus::NoAccess** (title does not have write access to the container storage space). No changes on my end; the API just stopped working. It happens on PC but not Xbox.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an issue that is likely the cause. The change is happening, so try again in a while and let us know if you are still seeing issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, since stackoverflow likes to keep questions strictly about coding issues, you might want to post other questions here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=xboxlivedev

Comment: (I posted the same question to xboxlivedev, but the post never showed up in the forum.)